# How to detect that an XPATH expression is correct?

Tags: c#, xpath

Is there any way (regex or similar, c# preferred) to detect if an XPath expression is correct before using it?

I have been googling for some time and nothing seems to appear.

Thanks in advance!
Carlos.

Answer (score 1):

Try it and if there is a thrown XPathException, that mean your XPath is syntactically wrong.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

try 
{
  var res = nav.Compile(xpath);

  // ...
}
catch (XPathException e)
{
  // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: Is there any nicer way to do it without trying?

Comment: @charlypu If there is, I'm not aware, sry.

Comment: Why do you think this is not "nice"? Surely using an existing and well-tested XPath parser is a much nicer solution than crafting your own?